# Location services not updating in background

Tags: ios8, core-location

For iOS 8 I have added the following key to my plist:

> NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

I also added:

```
    // Check for iOS 8
    if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
```

I deleted the app from my phone.  Upon launch I get prompted if its ok to run location services in background as expected. I click yes.  While the app is running I get locations and the location active icon is in the status bar.

However if I leave the app the location active icon soon disappears from the status bar and I no longer get locations.

Do I need to re setup the location manager when the app enters the background?  Does the location manager property/variable need to be defined in the AppDelegate such that it never goes away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to set location updates in the background modes of your capabilities.

[image]